# PHP - multiple log in options if else if

Tags: php

Users can log on to my website either through a social network or manually via my website after they have registered.

Now Im doing the following to get the user id to display the correct result for the user

```
if(isset($_SESSION['fbid'])){
uid = $_SESSION['fbid']; //social media login
//do stuff
}
else if(isset($_SESSION['myMembers'])){
uid=$_SESSION['myMembers'] //through website
//do same stuff
}
```

It just seems awfully cumbersome to have an if else if statement containing exactly the same code just to get the method through which the user log in, and my code is becoming very long and confusing because of this

Can anyone offer me some advice on how I can alternatively tackle this problem?

Comment: You can use ternary operators http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$uid = ( isset($_SESSION['fbid'] ) ? $_SESSION['fbid'] : 
         ( isset($_SESSION['myMembers'] ? isset($_SESSION['myMembers'] : null);

if ( isset( $uid ) )
{
    //do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should do something like that?

```
if(isset($_SESSION['fbid'])){
$uid = $_SESSION['fbid']; //social media login
}
else if(isset($_SESSION['myMembers'])){
$uid=$_SESSION['myMembers']; //through website
}

if(isset($_SESSION['fbid']) || isset($_SESSION['myMembers']){
//do stuff
//do same stuff
}
```

Comment: ok but when code executes does $uid = $_SESSION['FBID'] or $_SESSION['myMembers']

Comment: It should do it. Aswell we can just check if isset($uid).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you keep separate session for different login option? For me, I would as the following:

### Database

```
users       (user_id, name)
users_login (user_id, login_type, auth, password)
```

Sample Data

```
users
(1, "Marilee")

users_login
(1, "FB", "100004890275000", null)
(1, "MY", "marilee", "iloveyou")
```

### Login

When you login with any login, you only need to keep one session (or two session). Just keep the ID of the user or maybe also store what login option the user has login (this is optional).